# How can I copy and paste a video on MacOS?

Tags: macos, video, copy-paste

So I take a video on my iPhone, go the Photos app on my MacBook Pro, copy the video, and paste it into a message in the Messages app (on the MacBook). But the video is not pasted, only a still image from it is. If I use the share sheet to get the video from Photos to Messages, it works as expected, but I'd find copy/paste more natural. How can I set things up to copy/paste videos from Photos to other apps under MacOS?

I'm new to MacOS (less than two weeks!), so forgive me if this is elementary. Googling for the problem just yielded links to videos on copying and pasting.

Both the iPhone and the MacBook are running the latest versions of their OSes.

Comment: Have you tried drag-and-drop video from Photos app to destination app? It works for Messages and probably in other apps as well.

Comment: Drag and drop works with Messages. (It doesn't work with WhatsApp.) However, drag and drop is less convenient than copy/paste, because to drag and drop, I believe both apps have to be in the same Space (i.e., virtual desktop), and it is not uncommon for me to want to copy from Photos in one Space and to paste into a different app (e.g., Messages) in a different Space.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't aware of this either, but "Copy" in Photos only seems to copy a picture of the current video, not the video itself. As you found out already, you can use the Share function instead.

But there is an even easier way, which doesn't require having Photos open at all. Just open Messages, click on the A icon left to the entry field

[image]

select "Photos" and then pick the video you want to share from the Photos picker.

PS: The "Photos" picker is also available in all "Open File" dialogs.

Comment: So I guess it's not just me that "copying" a video doesn't actually copy it. Thank you, Apple. Your suggestion for Messages works fine, but the advantage of copy/paste is that it should work across pretty much all apps. I might want to copy a video and paste it into a WhatsApp message (which, sadly, is not a share sheet destination option on MacOS and doesn't seem to have a Photos picker) or a document of some kind. The strength of copy/paste is its generality. It's frustrating that for videos, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe In documents, you usually can insert anything (incouding videos from Photos) via the Open File dialog.

Comment: Hmmm, in the Pages app, File>Open brings up a file picker, but I can't find a way to select a photo, much less a video to insert. If I select "Pictures" in the left sidebar, I can see "Photos Library.photoslibrary", but it's greyed out, and I can't select it. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe File->Open opens *Pages* documents. To insert other content *into* a Pages document, select Insert->Image Gallery and click on the icon at bottom right of the placeholder in the document (you can also drag&drop from Photos if this suits you better).

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe Please ask a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t think about in terms of copy/paste (those are editing terms) especially when going from your iPhone to your Mac; I assume you’re trying to get videos from your iPhone using messaging. Instead, think of it as “sharing” files from one place to another.

- AirDrop.  This will allow you to do a wireless transfer of the file (video) from your iPhone to your Mac.  Instead of attaching the video to a message, sending it to yourself, then saving it on your computer for further processing can become burdensome. AirDrop is a  quick and easy way to transfer files back and forth (I used it for the iPhone screenshot used here)
- Share Sheet Items.  The Share Sheet is pretty intuitive and mostly self explanatory.  But, there will be times when you’re presented with additional options and options like “Export Unmodified Original” are
  context sensitive;  you get this option when attempting to share a
  video.

  - share via Messaging
  - to Contact(s)
  - to a different Application
  - Save to Files (App)
  - Export Unmodified Original (Photos & Video)

The share sheet is pretty intuitive and mostly self explanatory.  But if you scroll down, you’ll find additional options and items like “Export Unmodified Original” are context sensitive;  you get this option when attempting to share a video.

[image]

Comment: My question is specifically about MacOS, because that's where I want to send the video from. On my Mac, the share sheet options for a video in Photos has none of the extra options you show.

Comment: It’s better then to show us your share sheet and post that image to the question. Each person’s sheet will be different depending on what they installed and enabled.  Mine even has custom Shortcuts which I created, so you won’t match with mine.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible to post images as part of comments. I'll see if I can figure out a way to create a link to a cloud-based image. I'm not going to add the image to my original post, because that's about copy/paste, and now we're into share sheets.

Comment: That’s why I said post it to the *question*.  Just post what you see…share sheets falls under copy paste